How to compose a notification from device instead of Firebase console in Flutter using FCM HTTP v1 API?
I wanted to compose a Firebase notification from the device in my Flutter app instead of using the Firebase console and then send that notification to the user at another time similar to the Weather app notification.
However, everybody is using the Firebase console for composing notifications. As "Cloud Messaging API" is deprecated, I need to use the new "FCM HTTP v1 API". There is a migration guide Migration guide but it is not very clear. For example, it does not tell how to handle push notification click in Flutter. I cannot use Activity Intent as mentioned in the guide because I am using Flutter.
My second concern is that using a .json file exposes all the keys to the client. How can we handle it securely?
Any help? Thanks.

Sending messages to a device through Firebase Cloud Messaging (so-called downstream messages) requires that you specify credentials that provide credentials that allow sending any message to any device in the project. For this reason, sending downstream messages can only be securely done from a trusted environment, such as the Firebase console, your development machine, a server you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. Sending messages directly from one device to another is not a supported use-case in FCM.

@FrankvanPuffelen A Lot of apps are sending notifications from one device to another. For example, Ride-sharing apps.

No they aren't. The notifications are sent from a server. Now it may be another app instance that calls/triggers that server, but the API call to FCM to send a downstream message happens on a trusted environment and not from the app instance. If not, the app runs the same risk I mentioned above.

@FrankvanPuffelen. You are right about security but the idea I am working with, I need to send notifications on the same device but at a later time. How you can say that it is not a supported use case in FCM because you can do it and is mentioned in the documentation.

To send notification from one device to another from within the app, you need to make a post request to the following url:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

I used Dio to create a post request. You can use http or any other package you like.
Dio dio = Dio();
    var result = await dio.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        data: {
          "to" : "the_token_you_will_send_notification_to",
          "priority": "high",
          "notification": {
            "title": "Title",
            "body" : "First Notification",
            "text": "Text"
          }
        },
        options: Options(
            headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json ',
          'Authorization':
              'key=your_fcm_server_key'
        }));

    print(result);

To get your fcm server key, please visit your firebase console project settings. From project settings, go to 'Cloud Messaging' tab. Then copy your server key and paste it in your Authorization header. Make sure to add key eg: 'key=your_server_key'.
Also, replace the 'to' parameter with the Firebase Messaging token of the user you want to send notification to.

How to get fcm server key? because Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) is deprecated and I am unable to load it from my console. Therefore I need to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

How I can handle notification click if I use fcm on Flutter?
